# Finding code that will fire off sql server triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of triggers in my database and their parent tables and I would like to find the origin event that eventually fires the triggers off.  I have a number of projects that utilize the database that include Silverlight, ASP.net and WPF.  All apps are required to use stored procedures for DML.

Other than scripting the stored procedures into a text file and then performing a manual search, is there a way to query my stored procedures "guts" to find insert and updates on the trigger's parent tables?  I'm thinking there is a sys view or something I could use.

Once I'm able to pinpoint the stored procedures, I can then search the project source code and identify events that call the DML.

Comment: This sounds like a job for... {insert fanfare}... SQL Profiler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query can give you that info

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%<table_name_here>%'
```

Comment: Charles - thanks for the guidance.  I used your info and came up with the following to generate tql for the object definition.

Select name, 
'select OBJECT_DEFINITION(' + cast(object_id as varchar(50)) + ') UNION ' as [guts]
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%SECURITY_USERINFO%'

Comment: If you believe this answered your question I would ask that you accept the answer so others can find this information and see there is an answer out there.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple external events that are using same stored procedure that fires a trigger then just finding stored procedures will not help because you will not know what external event started it.

You can use sys tables to find stored procedures that are manipulating the data and firing triggers but that won’t help you in identifying which event fired it in the first place.

You would need profiler for this that can help you capture application, host machine and other details needed to figure this out.